# Вычисления в javascript

Tags: javascript

Вот пример : `M^1.66057^10( в -27 степени)`

M - вводится в текстовое поле.

Я пробовал сделать так, но не работает:

```
A=M^1.66057^pow(10,-27)
```

Когда убираю `pow(10,-27)` то работает нормально. Может число очень маленькое. 
Подскажите как это решить

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В большинстве языков программирования для записи подобных  чисел есть специальная форма. Мнемоническое правило звучит так - то, что произноситься как "умножить на 10 в степени" заменяется на `e`. Поэтому 10 в -27 степени записывается как `1e-27`. (потому что в записи 10 в -27 нет слова умножить и полное название звучит как 1 **умножить на 10 в степени** -27).

А вот символ `^` - это не степень. Это побитовое исключающее или. И применять его для вещественных чисел как то не красиво. (хотя по факту, вещественное число будет приведено к целому и все будет работать, но не факт, что так, как хочется).

`pow` у Вас скорее всего не работает, потому что его нужно записывать как `Math.pow()` - так требует синтаксис.

Теперь попробую расшифровать, что же записано в условии.

> M^1.66057^10( в -27 степени)

это словами выходит М в степени 1.66057e-27 (помните о `e`?) Но даже достаточно большое число в такой степени это будет чуточку больше единицы. Причем это "чуточку" - настолько маленькое, что при расчетах можно пренебречь (если это только не какая то специальная область).

Может переформулируете словами?

Comment: Наверное какую-то физику человек считает.

Просто [Атомная единица массы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B) == 1,660538782(83)E-27 кг -- очень уж похоже.

Comment: я об этом думал. И видимо умножение нужно.

Comment: Конечно, нужно. 

Только вот есть различие в 5-м знаке после запятой. Интересно, ТС расскажет, что он считает?

Может что-то связанное с радиоуглеродным анализом.

Comment: некоторые справочники дают и значение `1.66057e-27`. Гугл находит много подобного.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Надо было просто подставить 'Math' перед 'pow'. Вы правы это атомная еденица массы. Мне это надо для вычисления кол -ва атомов в веществе но тут я не написал точной формулы

Comment: У меня получился такой ответ ......3e+26 . А как можно заменить ......3e+26 на ......3 умножить на 10 в 26 стапени?

Comment: Нужен красивый вывод? напишите себе функцию. Что то в таком стиле

    function prettyprint(x)
    {
      var c = 1e5; // для красивого округления мантисы
      var b = Math.log(x) / Math.log(10); // находим порядок
      b = Math.round(b); // порядок - целое, поэтому округлим
      var a = x / Math.pow(10,b); // рассчитаем мантису
      a = Math.round(a * c) / c; // и округлим её красиво
      return a + "×10<sup>"+b+"</sup>"; // и собственно форматирование.
    }

функция, возможно не идеальная, но для учебных заданий - предостаточно.